# How can I add custom commands by overlaying selenium ide?

Tags: overlay

I am overlaying Selenium IDE and it looks like that the adding of my extension doesn't allow me to create my own commands. In order to do this, I create a user-extension.js file with my custom commands. The problem is that they are not taken account with the overlaying.

Could you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are headed in the right direction, although several things could be the problem. user_extensions.js needs to have valid code, it needs to be linked up to Selenium IDE, etc.

Perhaps reading this will help: http://www.codediesel.com/testing/adding-custom-commands-to-the-selenium-ide/

It is a good tutorial, and I was able to add my own commands to Selenium IDE by following its instructions.